# Excluding last element of array with slice

Tags: javascript, arrays, slice

In an application I am working with arrays of coordinates - when I log the points of feature to the console, I am returned an array of 5 coordinate pairs:

```
var poly = data.features[0].geometry.coordinates
console.log(poly)
```

[image]

However, when I use `slice()`  to exclude the *last* element of the array - which should return 4 instead of 5 - I am returned a blank array

```
var poly = data.features[0].geometry.coordinates.slice(0, -1);
console.log(poly)
```

[image]

Why does this happen and why doesn't the `slice()` method work in this case?

Comment: Try `data.features[0].geometry.coordinates.pop()`.

Comment: @Kinduser That would have the same problem as the OP. You mean `...coordinates[0].pop()` but only if you want to mutate the array in place, which `slice()` would not do.

Comment: @MichaelGeary I agree, but look what OP is doing, he assigns new value to the same variable - mutates it.

Comment: @Kinduser Where do you see that? OP's code creates a new array and assigns it to a new `poly` variable.

Comment: @MichaelGeary To a new `poly` variable? It's still the old one.

Comment: @the_darkside Something else to be aware of... It looks like you are using GeoJSON. You should be familiar with some of the terminology it uses and try to use consistent names in your code. In GeoJSON, a `polygon` is not just a single list of points as we would think of it in geometry. A `polygon` consists of one or more `rings`, the first one being the outer ring and subsequent ones being inner rings which are excluded from the region. (Think of a county with a lake inside it, for example.) So your `poly` variable may perhaps more properly be called `ring`.

Comment: @Kinduser OP's code is not mutating any array as `.pop()` would do. It creates a new array without modifying any existing array. `coordinates.pop()` (or the `coordinates[0].pop()` that OP was looking for) would mutate the array in place. `.slice()` does not change the original array, but instead creates a new one. You could verify this by inspecting the `geometry.coordinates` or `geometry.coordinates[0]` array after trying each version. `pop()` changes that array; `slice()` doesn't. Don't be misled by where the result gets stored; that's not the issue.

Comment: @Kinduser If it helps clarify things, imagine that there were no assignment into `poly` at all, just a call to `.slice()` or `.pop` without saving the result. `.slice()` would not change the original array; it would create a new array which would then be discarded. `.pop()` would remove the last element from the original array, so that array is now one element shorter.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelGeary, please see the comments I've made below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using GeoJSON data and you want to strip off the duplicate coordinate at the end of a ring. This being the case, you should be aware that your `coordinates` array (the one with a single element that has the array of points inside it) may actually contain more than one element. In GeoJSON, a `polygon` is not the same concept as in geometry. A geographic "polygon" consists of an outer "ring" and zero or more inner rings. A "ring" is like a polygon in geometry.

The first ring in a polygon - the single ring that your example has - is the "outer ring", that is the outer boundary of the area you're mapping. Any additional rings are "inner rings" which represent holes that are excluded from the area. For example, a state or county with two lakes in it might be represent as a polygon with three rings, one for the outer boundary and the other two for each of the lakes.

Also, are you checking `geometry.type` before assuming that `geometry.coordinates` is a `Polygon` at all? You may unexpectedly receive a `MultiPolygon`, which is an *array of polygons*, so now you have one more level of nested arrays. GeoJSON data sources will often use either a `Polygon` or `MultiPolygon` as needed.

Consider the state of Utah. It has a single outer boundary, and of course has the Great Salt Lake inside it (along with some smaller lakes). So Utah can be represented by a `Polygon` with outer ring for the state border and inner rings for the Great Salt Lake and other lakes.

But what about Hawaii? It consists of several islands. There is no single outer boundary for the state. Each island requires its own outer boundary. So Hawaii has to be represented by a `MultiPolygon`, i.e. an array of `Polygon` arrays. Each island gets its own `Polygon`.

Whatever code you're writing, it should take all this into account. You should distinguish between a `Polygon` and a `MultiPolygon` and for the latter, process each `Polygon` that makes up the `MultiPolygon`. And if you're stripping off the last element from each polygon's outer ring, you probably want to do that for the inner rings as well. For more details, see the [GeoJSON RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946).

I would provide some sample code to do all this, but I'm not clear enough on what you're working toward. But this should at least give you some direction.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Actually, what I am doing is using the intersect() function from the `turf.js` library.  I am consistently running into this message `found non-noded intersection between LINESTRING ` when I try to find the intersection between polygons, even though I've checked topology and there seem to be no errors in the geojson files

Comment: That error means that somewhere there is an intersection between two lines, but the intersection does not occur at a node (one of the points in each line). As a simple example, imagine a rectangle, and swap the coordinates of the northeast and southeast points. Now you have a shape like a bow tie. The place where two lines cross in the middle is not on any of the points of the polygon, so it is a non-noded intersection. (It would also be invalid GeoJSON because it wouldn't follow the winding rule, but we'll ignore that for now.)

Comment: Removing the last point of a polygon - the point that duplicates the first point - would also make it invalid GeoJSON, so I'm not sure how that would help anything. A polygon is required to have the first and last points the same. I would try testing the GeoJSON input on http://geojsonlint.com/ and http://mapshaper.org/ to see if either of those gives any hints.

Comment: As another example, suppose you have two rectangles of the same size, positioned side by side so the right edge of the rectangle on the left is the same as the left edge of the rectangle on the right. This would be a valid topology. Now take one of the rectangles and slide it up and over so they intersect. Now you have an invalid topology with non-noded intersections. There must be something like this happening, unless there's an error in turf.js since you mentioned you'd checked the topology.

Comment: @the_darkside ^ not sure if SO notifies you on my comments to my own answer since I didn't @ you, so just a ping in case you didn't see them.

Answer (score 3):

Poly is an array with a single element, what you really want is

```
var poly = data.features[0].geometry.coordinates[0].slice(0, -1);
```

Comment: Thanks - yes this returns:  `[Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2)]`  but I am looking for the exact same structure as what the first query returns -  to keep the array as a single element but with 4 pairs of coordinates instead of 5.  I hope that makes sense.

Comment: data.features[0].geometry.coordinates[0].pop(); var poly = data.features[0].geometry.coordinates @the_darkside

Answer (score 0):

As you can see on your screenshot,

```
var poly = data.features[0].geometry.coordinates
```

returns [Array(5)] which is essentially a two dimensional array. To exclude the last element in the nested array, you'll need to do

```
// coordinates[0] returns the first item in the array which is Array(5)    
var poly = data.features[0].geometry.coordinates[0].slice(0, -1);
```

To keep a two dimensional array minus the last coordinate pair instead, you need to recursively clone each element.

```
var poly = data.features[0].geometry.coordinates.map(function(val) {
    return val.slice(0, -1);
});
```

Comment: thanks - I would like to keep a two dimensional array minus the last coordinate pair.  So instead of `[Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2)]` which is what `data.features[0].geometry.coordinates[0].slice(0, -1);` returns -  I am looking to keep the two dimensional array